# profile pic(thumbnail) of friends using graph api in facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Have a simple problem to load my friend list in table view and asynchronously load their profile-pic thumbnails. I just couldn't figure out the correct url for the thumbnail image. could anyone help me out with the url of the display pic of friends

Comment: is it https://graph.facebook.com/<friends_profile_id>/picture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a FQL to get list of facebook friends & their Pics

```
 NSString *query = @"SELECT uid,name,first_name,last_name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (";
query = [query stringByAppendingFormat:@"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = %@)",userid];
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                query, @"query",
                                nil];
[_facebook requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" 
                       andParams: params
                   andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                     andDelegate:self];
```

you will get a array in u r

```
  -(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
```

Sample
      {
        "first_name" =User;
        "last_name" = R;
        name = "User R";
        "pic_square" = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/.jpg";
        uid = 595sd1;
         }
     {},{} etc

Hope this helps!

Comment: i do not understand the format : upto **uid IN("** its in red then there is a semicolon.. Structure is bit awkward..

Comment: @Patel : copy exactly & run u r program - its a join query userid="user fb ID"